# Spark Job using HDFS disk storage to complete the job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I trigger the Spark-submit on EMR Cluster which has the free dfs storage of 4gb. My job is reading the 80GB of input parquet file and 4gb parquet file, doing the transformations and writing out the output to S3://. Here the job fails due to insufficient hdfs storage.

> > When I clear the dfs storage and make the 10gb of free hdfs:/// storage available. The job gets succeeded.

Can any one please explain how physical hdfs storage helps in completing the Spark-job, For what it is being used during the transformations. As Spark does the computations in memory.

Comment: please see what is set for spark.local.dir? If that is the HDFS then it explains this

Comment: Thanks for reply. I could not find this in the spark-defaults.conf file. Can you specify the location of config file where this setting can be found ? @Salim

Comment: I don't know where it is on EMR. You can see spark.local.dir under "environment" tab.